# MySQL - find specific number and remove it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have field which looks like this:

```
1,17,22,25,111,251,170
```

I need to find for example number 1 and just number 1, and remove it. Also I need to remove all commas if they exist at the start or end, and double commas to. Is there way to do this within MySQL?

Comment: Never, never, never store multiple values in one column! You arer better off changing your table design.

Comment: Do not clear please explain with example

Comment: In other words, you have a very crappy data-model and now you're having difficulties performing simple tasks. My first advice would be to normalize your database, then your question will become useless. If you don't want to do that, you better try to write some code first then come back here if you expect to get some help... But seriously, normalize your database !

Comment: Are you saving this as a string?

Comment: MySQL has string editing functionality, but it is bad design if your storing multiple values in one field. I urge you to reconsider your table layout, before you start chopping up strings.

Comment: This is not my DB, I just inherited and wanted first to see if I can work with this. So basically I need to remodel this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For removing preceding and trailing commas you can simply write:-

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(COL_NAME, ',', ' '))), ' ', ',');
```

AND for removing all 1 you can write:-

```
SELECT REPLACE(COL_NAME, '1', '');
```

If You Want Merge Them You Can Simply Write:-

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(COL_NAME, ',', ' '))), ' ', ',','1',''));
```

This might be helpful to you.

Comment: oops. BTW thanx to anonymous.

Comment: This is working, thanks :). But I think I will listen to advice and remodel table.